# For a commutative ring, prove the cancellation law.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ be a commutative ring. Prove the cancellation law: if $a\in R\setminus\{0\}$ is not a zero divisor, then $ab = ac$ implies $b = c$ for any $b,c\in R$.

My attempt:

We are given $a\in R\setminus\{0\}$ is not a zero divisor. Let $ab = ac$, then $ab = ac\implies ab-ac=0\implies a(b-c)=0$. Because $a$ is not a zero divisor, we can conclude that $b-c=0\implies b=c$.

I believe this is correct, but do you think I am being specific enough in my justification?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are. This is fine. Well maybe add the clause “… and $a ≠ 0$” to “Because $a$ is not a zero divisor …”. But that’s minor.

Comment: I think the current phrasing is fine.  It is unnecessary to mention $a\neq 0$ because (1) you are given $a\in R\setminus \{0\}$, and (2) you are directly applying the definition of "$a$ is not a zero divisor".

Comment: Thanks for you all's input. It's really easy to feel like I'm missing something when my proofs are really short. :D